# Pinia persist doesnt work when store is used in plugin with Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

Trying to use store in a plugin but I found out that states do not persist when a store is used in a plugin with Nuxt 3. When removed from plugin, persist works. Followed nuxt 3 doc to use pinia in plugin [nuxt 3 doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/configuration#vuex)

```
// store/test.ts

export const useTestStore = defineStore('test-store', {
  state: () => ({
    count: 0,
  }),
  actions: {
    addCount() {
      this.count++;
    },
  },
  persist: {
    storage: persistedState.localStorage,
  },
});
```

```
// plugin/store.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ $pinia }) => {
  return {
    provide: {
      store: useTestStore($pinia),
    },
  };
});
```

Reproduction using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-lvetcm?file=plugins%2Fstore.ts,nuxt.config.ts,pages%2Findex.vue,store%2Ftest.ts)

Comment: I see you also posted the question to the [pinia-plugin-persistedstate](https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate) library's github repository ([#190](https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/issues/190)), you will likely have more change of an answer there since it's specific to the library.

Comment: yep, just wanted to get more visibility on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of pinia persist has gotten back to me, turns out you should skip defining the plugin in nuxt.config and it will work. Link to issue: https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/issues/190